# Commutators and implications of them not equalling 0

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, commutator

I'm struggling to understand the commutator theory for quantum mechanics. I know there's the proof to do with $[P,Q]=0$ therefore there is a set of simultaneous eigenstates for $P$ and $Q$. However, if $[P,Q] \neq 0$, does it also mean that then for all $|\psi\rangle \neq 0$, we have $[P,Q]|\psi\rangle \neq 0$? Or there is a way for it to equal 0?

Comment: Can a general linear map have a nonzero kernel?

Comment: @NDewolf Well, you've got $T(u) = 0_V$ but the kernel contains a set of vectors

Comment: Two non-commuting operators can share an eigenvector.  They just can't share *all* of them. If $|\psi\rangle$ is an eigenvector, then the commutator acting on this vector will give zero. I provide some clarification [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/221007/mutual-or-same-set-of-eigenfunctions-if-two-operators-commute/221022#221022).

Comment: There is no such thing as $\psi=0$.

Answer (score 1):

As a counterexample:  in general, the operators $\hat{L}_x$ and $\hat{L}_y$ do not commute, since $[\hat{L}_x, \hat{L}_y] = i \hbar \hat{L}_z$.  However, for any state $|\psi\rangle \neq 0$ which is an eigenvector of $\hat{L}_z$ with $L_z = 0$, we have $[L_x, L_y] |\psi\rangle = 0$.